# How to use personality-insights-chart?

Tags: javascript, json, sunburst-diagram, personality-insights

I created my own API using the IBM Watson Personality Insights API. Then, I created a website that would retrieve the the JSON object from the API and display it in a sunburst diagram, just like in the Personality Insights Demo.

I have found a library that displays the information how I want from a JSON object: https://github.com/personality-insights/sunburst-chart . The problem is that the instructions say that I must insert this two lines of code into my HTML file:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.14/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/personality-sunburst-chart.standalone.js"></script>
```

I know the second line must be changed accordingly to where personality-sunburst-chart.standalone.js is, but that file doesn't exist in the library. I thought that maybe they had changed the library and forgot to update the instructions, so I tried pointing it to index.js file inside the /lib folder of the library. Once I did that the browser console started alerting me that the file couldn't be executed because it contained require() commands, that can't be executed in web JavaScript.

**Where can I get the missing file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

**Explanation**

In all 1.x.x versions of the library, the whole library came precompiled in the /bin directory in the form of a JavaScript file named "personality-sunburst-chart.standalone.js".
The current version is 2.x.x, the installation method changed, but the instructions weren't changed.

**Current installation instructions for the 2.x.x version**

The current version doesn't come with a precompiled file. To get it, you have to follow the following instructions:

You have to download the repository and run `npm install` to install all the necessary dependencies. After that, you must run `npm run compile`. Once that finishes, the standalone file will be in the /dist directory with the name index.js.

The command script is: `node_modules/.bin/browserify --full-paths -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] --standalone PersonalitySunburstChart lib/index.js -o dist/index.js`

You can then change the name to "personality-sunburst-chart.standalone.js" if you want and copy it to your web page directory.

Then, you can reference the final script with :

```html
<script src="personality-sunburst-chart.standalone.js"></script>
```